# SyntaxError: EOL error due to the command instruction

Tags: python, command, tcp

I am trying to "convert" a labview program into a python code which controls instruments. I connect to the device via TCP-IP. The issue is that the commands I have to send consist a straight quotation mark (') which I believe cause a SyntaxError. A typical command that works in LabView is `(param-disp 'laser1:serial-number)` so the code I use is

```
import socket
import logging

TCP_IP = '192.168.1.1'
TCP_PORT = 5000
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
MESSAGE = (param-disp 'laser1:serial-number)\n

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.send(MESSAGE)
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
s.close()

print ("received data:", data)
```

And I got this error: "SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal".
If it ends with `\n'` then I got "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" error. I just started to code in Python an apparently I am missing something. What would it be?

Comment: Pay attention to your single quotes, MESSAGE should be written like:  `MESSAGE = '(param-disp laser1:serial-number)\n'`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use string quotes:

```
MESSAGE = "(param-disp 'laser1:serial-number)\n"
```

In Python, you should always use `"` - quotes to indicate strings. You can then use inline <kbd>`</kbd> characters.

Comment: Always use `"`? Python treats single quotes the same as double quotes. However the problem is `'` and not `

Comment: It's common to use `"` quotes in python. It's the same in Java, where `'` are single characters! My code should work, doesn't it? Did I miss something? The `'`-problem should be gone.

Comment: I hear you, but python accepts both as a sting type. For example both `print type('a')` and `print type("a")` have the same output: `<type 'str'>`

Comment: As I already said... both are valid. But `"` is the more common way.

Comment: P.S. you posted `print type('a')`, which is a Python 2 command. Whenever possible, you should use Python 3 ( `print(type('a'))` ). It's just a hint.